# Why does Panda return a ValueError in this case?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas beginner here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7]})

newdf=pd.DataFrame()

i=0
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if df.loc[i] != df.loc[i-1]:
        newdf.append(df.loc[i])
    else:
        pass
print(newdf)
```

Why do I get a this:  "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"?

Is there another way to check if the value of a column for a row is equal/not equal to that of the previous row?

Comment: The answers are a good way to shorten your entire program into one line but about the error it occurs because `df.loc[i] != df.loc[i-1]` returns an array of booleans, use `(df.loc[i] != df.loc[i-1]).any()` to convert it into a single boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python if-statement is not capable to handle the result of comparison of 2 dataframe rows, which will result in a boolean index of more than one entry.  Hence, the error.

Instead, you should use Pandas operation without using if-statement and select the rows matching your condition by [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), as follows:

```
newdf = df.loc[df['A'] != df['A'].shift()]
```

Result:

```
print(newdf)


   A
0  1
1  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
8  6
9  7
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the values are the same next to eachother use the shift operator:

```
df["A"] == df["A"].shift(1)
Out[87]: 
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
8     False
9     False
10     True
```

to complete:

```
new_df = df[df["A"]==df["A"].shift(1)]
```